# Can globalize-compiler expose CLDR data too?

Tags: jquery-globalize, cldr

I am using globalize-compiler to statically load Globalize 1.3.0 and CLDR data. However, I would like to also consume some of the CLDR data directly, for example, to access the value of `numbers/symbols-numberSystem-latn/decimal` like in *Globalize 0.1.1* using `.findClosestCulture()`.

Looking at the compiled formatters, the data is not accessible:

```
Globalize.b1148906457 = numberFormatterFn(["",,1,,,,,,,,"","0","-0",
    "-","",numberRound(),"∞","NaN",{".":",",",":".","%":"%","+":"+",
    "-":"-","E":"E","‰":"‰"},]);
```

Is there any Globalize method or globalize-compiler flag to make CLDR accessible? Do I need to use cldrjs instead?

Answer (score 1):

Maintainer here... It can't. I'm open for ideas on how to make that happen. Possibly this might be helpful https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/issues/605#issuecomment-205799565